# .NET core app deploy to local IIS, 500.19

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, iis-7, localhost

I am trying deploy a net Core webApi in IIS. I have IIS configured as seen in the images, but is not running the WEBAPI. I get error 500.19 as it is also seen in the images. On that same computer I run the web api from the executable or from the dll with dotnet and it works correctly, below I leave you some reference images and the web.config code. I hope you can help, thank you very much !!

WEBCONFIG>>

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
  For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\YangSoft.WebAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44320" />
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: e014a839-088c-484e-9bda-6a2ce51f0de6-->
```

I was long hours surfing here and google and I really can not find the solution.

IMgs:

```html
    https://ibb.co/N3h59kQ
    https://ibb.co/LRdSktk
    https://ibb.co/rvYn8Z8
    https://ibb.co/vsTMm3T
    https://ibb.co/VjwgyMv
    https://ibb.co/ykdGZpm
    https://ibb.co/Q8RB96W
```

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report and the cause should be clear.

Comment: how do i run this report? i havent this option in my IIS.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/install.html

Comment: Any alternative or suggestion? That does not work well in windows 10, I run it as admin and it does not open.
tnx a lot

Comment: Just published release 12.0.93.0. It should now run and provide you the report.

Comment: do you have the Core Windows Server Hosting installed?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the last image.

Comment: @LexLi, you are the developer, good tool!